# Angular material table borders not full length

Tags: html, css, angular

Im trying to create a nice looking table. Because of the content soon to be comming in the matrix part, i cant make it smaller for mobile devices. So i added overflow:auto to get a scroll-bar.

The problem is that the horizontal lines wont extend to the whole table, it cuts off at the part behind the scroll.

[Before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XB1Uo.png)

[After scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JCPg.png)

HTML

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="module">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [ngClass]="'smallCell'"> Module</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let moduleData" [ngClass]="'smallCell'"> {{moduleData.module}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="specialisation">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [ngClass]="'smallCell'"> Spec</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let moduleData" [ngClass]="'smallCell'">
      <mat-list dense>
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let specialisation of moduleData.specialisation"> {{specialisation}}</mat-list-item>
      </mat-list>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="period">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [ngClass]="'smallCell'"> Periode</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let moduleData" [ngClass]="'smallCell'"> {{moduleData.period}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="matrix">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [ngClass]="'matrixCell'"> Matrix</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let moduleData" [ngClass]="'matrixCell'"> {{moduleData.matrix}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="endRequirements">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [ngClass]="'requirmentCell'"> Eindeisen</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let moduleData" [ngClass]="'requirmentCell'">
      <mat-list>
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let requirement of moduleData.endRequirements"> {{requirement}}</mat-list-item>
      </mat-list>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let moduleRowData; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Css

```
.table-container{
  height: calc(100vh - 114px);
  overflow: auto;
}

.requirmentCell{
  flex: 0 0 325px;
}

.matrixCell{
  flex: 0 0 550px;

}

.smallCell{
  flex: 0 0 110px;

}
```

*edit*
Further tinkering around, its not just the border that is cutoff there. Its any css like, background color and the header.

Comment: Also its my first stackoverflow post, any tips about the post itself are also welcome!

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz to reproduce your issue?  You can fork the example given by Angular Material: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing similar issue: styles were applied only to visible part of the table, part "behind" a scroll was missing borders. Setting `display: table` to mat-table fixed it for me:

```js
.table-container {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

mat-table {
  display: table;
}
```